# How to use 'contains' in SQLAlchemy Queries in order to make use of MSSQL Full-text index

Tags: python, sql-server, sqlalchemy, azure-sql-database, flask-sqlalchemy

MSSQL has two operators ['contains'](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/queries/contains-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver16) and ['like'](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/language-elements/like-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver16) which behave differently:

- Contains performs full-text search only on full-text indexed columns
- Like does not need the column to be indexed

Contains is typically faster:
https://www.mytecbits.com/microsoft/sql-server/like-vs-contains

I have an SQLAlchemy query using 'Like':

```
if 'FullName' in data:
    filters.append(People.FullName.like('%' + data['FullName'] + '%'))
```

If I change the query to use 'Contains':

```
if 'FullName' in data:
    filters.append(People.FullName.contains(data['FullName']))
```

The echo returns pretty much the same thing, both use like, neither actually uses 'contains':

```
FROM [People]
WHERE [People].[FullName] LIKE ? 
 ORDER BY [People].[Id] DESC
 OFFSET ? ROWS
 FETCH FIRST ? ROWS ONLY
2022-06-08 15:51:23,247 INFO sqlalchemy.engine.Engine [generated in 0.00312s] ('%Bob%', 0, 100)
```

```
FROM [People]
WHERE ([People].[FullName] LIKE '%' + ? + '%')
 ORDER BY [People].[Id] DESC
 OFFSET ? ROWS
 FETCH FIRST ? ROWS ONLY
2022-06-08 15:49:40,280 INFO sqlalchemy.engine.Engine [generated in 0.00228s] ('Bob'), 0, 100)
```

SQLAlchemy documentation references [Contains](https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/14/core/sqlelement.html#sqlalchemy.sql.expression.ColumnElement.contains) which produces an expression `column LIKE '%' || <other> || '%'`.  I don't seem to find an example where SQLAlchemy makes use of 'contains'.

Does anyone know how to make SQLAlchemy use 'contains' in order for me to make use of the full text index?  I would expect the query to look something like:

```
FROM [People]
WHERE CONTAINS([People].[FullName], ?)
 ORDER BY [People].[Id] DESC
 OFFSET ? ROWS
 FETCH FIRST ? ROWS ONLY
2022-06-08 15:49:40,280 INFO sqlalchemy.engine.Engine [generated in 0.00228s] ('Bob'), 0, 100)
```

Or is the only solution to write the query as SQL?

Many thanks :-)

Answer (score 0):

All the methods `like()`, `contains()`, `startswith()` and `endswith()` function in the same way. According to the following official documentation of SQLAlchemy, any of the above methods, when used, internally creates an expression using `LIKE` operator and then it is evaluated to get the results.

[Column Elements and Expressions — SQLAlchemy 1.4 Documentation](https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/14/core/sqlelement.html)

So, if your query needs to be better in terms of performance, it is better to use SQL query. But using SQLAlchemy for `contains()` method will result in the same output as using `LIKE` operator in SQL.